# Django sort and regroup multiple fields

Tags: python, django, sorting

I am trying to regroup a field and sort on another in Django. My use case is different, but let's use the Django regroup template as an example.

Using this dataset.

```
cities = [
   {'name': 'Mumbai', 'population': '19,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
   {'name': 'Calcutta', 'population': '15,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
   {'name': 'New York', 'population': '20,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
   {'name': 'Chicago', 'population': '7,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
   {'name': 'Tokyo', 'population': '33,000,000', 'country': 'Japan'},
]
```

Using the regroup tag, this is the output:

1. India

   - Mumbai: 19,000,000
   - Calcutta: 15,000,000
2. USA

   - New York: 20,000,000
   - Chicago: 7,000,000
3. Japan

   - Tokyo: 33,000,000

---

How can I sort this information by population and yet still keep the grouping? This is the expected output that I would like to see:

1. Japan

   - Tokyo: 33,000,000
2. USA

   - New York: 20,000,000
   - Chicago: 7,000,000
3. India

   - Mumbai: 19,000,000
   - Calcutta: 15,000,000

How would one query the database to keep the groupings that are needed for reorder in the Django template to work properly and yet still maintain the sort order of population? How would this work on a date object instead of an int?

Answer (score 1):

> Note that {% regroup %} does not order its input! Our example relies on the fact that the cities list was ordered by country in the first place. If the cities list did not order its members by country, the regrouping would naively display more than one group for a single country.

define it in your queryset:

`def get_queryset(self):
     qs = self.model.objects.all()
     qs = qs.order_by('population', '-country')
     return qs`